# JMeter-Passing an id value from Response Header in path of next HTTP Request

Tags: jmeter

I have following Response headers info from first HTTP Request:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

set-cookie: x-usercontext=x-language=en&x-client=000; path=/

content-type: application/json

content-length: 7350

x-csrf-token: MiMegLCohX2qMT42ba3lzA==

cache-control: no-cache

x-rewriteurl: /x(cz1TSUQlM2FBTk9OJTNhbGRjaWtpd19LSVdfMDAlM2FNeXBWZklCU3pCOF9rUlB6S01TN2w4TmMxVERJTUNSRThBX1Q5RU1MLUFUVA==)/bw/ina/GetServerInfo

x-url-session-id: **x(cz1TSUQlM2FBTk9OJTNhbGRjaWtpd19LSVdfMDAlM2FNeXBWZklCU3pCOF9rUlB6S01TN2w4TmMxVERJTUNSRThBX1Q5RU1MLUFUVA==)**

x-server: true

x-perf-fesrec: 14161.000000

I must put the sequence of the x-url-session-id into the path of the next HTTP Request as below:

http://test.xxx.xxx.xxx:50000/**{x-url-session-id}**/bw/ina/GetResponse?xxx-client=000&xxx-language=en_UK&xxx-sessionviaurl=X

I tried to use Regex Extractor but I can not put the needed id as ${x-url-session-id} because I get the error:

java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 35:

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50000/${x-url-session-id}/bw/ina/GetResponse?xxx-client=000&xx-language=en_UK&xxx-sessionviaurl=X

```
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.toURI(Unknown Source)
```

Is there a way to put the given value from the first HTTP request as an part of the path in the second HTTP Request?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 1):

It means that your `${x-url-session-id}` variable is not defined, most probably due to incorrect Regular Expression Extractor configuration, double check it using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) and if this is the case - make sure to properly configure the Regular Expression Extractor, in particular it needs to be applied to [Response Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

Also if there is a redirection in place you also need to apply it to sub samples as well.

Example setup:

[image]